# How can I find out that my proxy server does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy

For example I have a proxy server like this 91.229.248.75:8085 and if it work I should receive `true` or if it does not work I should receive `false`, how can I do it with RoR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

Install net-ping gem by

```
 gem install net-ping
```

Then use this to check proxy:

```
 require 'net/ping'

 Net::Ping::TCP.new('91.229.248.75', 8085).ping
```

For example:

```
 Net::Ping::TCP.new('www.google.com', 80).ping
```